# Problems with PHP System_Daemon and IMAP connection

Tags: php, imap, daemon

I'm trying to create a PHP daemon that connects to an IMAP server and processes emails as they come in.  I have it close to working, but the daemon keeps grabbing the original emails that it finds the first time the daemon is loaded.  I believe the reason is because I'm opening the IMAP connection in the parent process. Example below:

```
if ($imapConnection=imap_open($authhost,$user,$pass) or die())
{
  //start daemon
  while()
  {
    //Grab email headers 
    $imapHeaders = imap_headers($imapConnection);
    $count = sizeof($imapHeaders)

    //loop the emails
    for($i = 1; $i <= $count, $i++)
    {
      //process the email
      //delete the email
    }

    System_Daemon::iterate(15);
  }
}   
imap_close($imapConnection);
```

I'd like to stay away from putting the IMAP connection within the loop.  How can I keep the connection to the IMAP server outside of the loop and still get new emails?

Answer (score 1):

In IMAP, mails stay on the server. So each time you come, if you have not explicitly removed them, old emails are still there. To prevent processing these emails, you could have a var that keeps the amount of mails you treated before, so you could go from $i = 0 (supposed the last arrived) to $i < $var where $var stands for the number of mails already treated.

EDIT :

Since you delete the mail by imap_delete, do an imap_expunge at each loop.

EDIT 2 :

Use imap_reopen, I tried you script on my server using `imap_reopen($imapConnection, "{domain.tld}INBOX");` after each loop and it sees the new mail now. Does not do a new authentication, just move your stream.

Comment: I actually delete the emails within the loop after I'm done processing them.  Do I still need to do what you are suggesting if I'm deleting the emails?

Comment: Also, once the daemon is started, it does not appear to find new emails that came in afterwards. That is why I think it has something to do with having the connection outside of the loop. It doesn't even know that I deleted emails and continues to loop over the same ones.

Comment: Ok. Maybe you have a cache problem and you could try [imap_open](http://fr.php.net/manual/en/function.imap-open.php) with option OP_SHORTCACHE ?

Comment: Another question. Do you only do a imap_delete ? or do you do and imap_expunge after ?

Comment: I'm not sure what the shortcache is. I'll have to look in to that a bit.

I do a imap_delete($imapConnection, $msgNum) Which, seems to work correctly.

Comment: From PHP.net : 

imap_delete marks messages listed in msg_number for deletion. Messages marked for deletion will stay in the mailbox until either imap_expunge() is called or imap_close() is called with the optional parameter CL_EXPUNGE.

Maybe here is your problem, if no expunge is done, you current connection will still see the messages in the inbox.

Comment: hmmm I'll give it a try, but that wouldn't explain why new emails aren't being found.  I still think it has something to do with the imap_open() not begin within the loop.  It doesn't seem to be getting the new messages every 15 seconds, which it should.